# Change orientation of camera preview in android depending on the orentation of the layout

Tags: android, orientation, android-camera

I display the Camera preview in surfaceView. In the surface callback I have this code in the surfaceChanged function:

```
                if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation== getResources().getConfiguration().ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                else
                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

This works ok it rotates the camera in portrait orientation. But the preview is wrongly orientated in when I change between I turn the tablet for 180 deegres. Is there a property which whether tablet is turn up or down, so that I can change the orientation recordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getRotation()`

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int orientation = display.getRotation();
```